# javascript regular expression does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

Trying to replace the contents of a td using regular expressions in my javascript function.  I'm using this...

```
var re = /<td id="idreplaceme">.+?<\/td>/gi;
oldDivContent = oldDivContent.replace(re,'<td id="idreplaceme"></td>');
```

This works in FF and Chrome but not IE8.  How do I make this work in IE8?

EDIT:
OldDivContent is a string

Comment: Simply print a message that IE8 is not supported. [And you will not be the first one doing this](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/01/bootstrapped-startup-saves-over-100k-by-dropping-ie/7/).

Comment: Is that even a valid regex? What does `.+?` mean?

Comment: What is `oldDivContent` defined as? A string? A DOMElement?

Comment: @DanTao it is valid. it makes the `.+` non-greedy

Comment: Here's a thought: How 'bout an example of the data on which this replacement is working on other browsers but not IE?

Comment: @DanTao a `?` following a `+` makes the `+` non-greedy. So, `.+?` means, one or more characters, matched non-greedily.

Comment: @lbstr: Ah, gotcha. So that is different from `.*`, then?

Comment: What is the content of oldDivContent? Please show us. Maybe it's not what you think it is on IE8.

Comment: What is your reason to use Regex here for parsing HTML, when you have great DOM functions available to you?

Comment: Works for me on IE8 (and Chrome), given reasonable assumptions about what the original content of `oldDivContent` is: http://jsbin.com/ajeqer, http://jsbin.com/ajeqer/2, http://jsbin.com/ajeqer/3, http://jsbin.com/ajeqer/4

Comment: Yes, it has to be the content of my string.  I can find no other explanation.  I'm still working on identifying it.  The string is a really really really large table and I cannot post it (*sigh* lawyers...).

Comment: Okay I stripped the data from the table and now the regex I posted in my OP works on all browsers.  What the hell!  I'm not sure what it was about the table content that IE8 doesn't like.  I give up.

Comment: @raido: It sounds like this question will never be usefully answered. I recommend using the "flag" link and asking the moderators to remove it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Why not `document.getElementById('idreplaceme').innerHTML = ''`

Comment: Was about to post this. The question makes a completely pointless use of regex, which this answer avoids. The pony he comes...

Comment: To be fair, he might be trying to do this replacement on some user input, e.g., something not in the DOM. Still, there are certainly more appropriate methods than using a regular expression.

Comment: Except for the *minor* detail that the original is a string, not in any way located in the DOM.

Comment: I would like to do it this way but for various reasons I only have the html string of this table.  I'm certain it has something to do with the difference in how IE and FF interpret my string content.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm suspicious of that, considering that the variable is named `oldDivContent`. Smells like an XY Problem to me.

Comment: @amnotiam: Not following you re "...an XY Problem..." :-) But the OP did come back and say, indeed, that it's a string, not something (currently) located in the DOM, see above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: *[XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)* as in *"I've decided that a regex is the best solution to my actual problem, so I'll just ask about that."* If it is indeed a string not originating from the DOM, I would wonder if it is destined for the DOM. If so, it should be parsed and added to the DOM with `.innerHTML` before manipulation. If not, I'd think that DOM manipulation would still be a better solution.

Comment: @amnotiam: And I don't disagree with that at all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try a slightly different regex:

```
var re = /<td id="idreplaceme">[^<]+<\/td>/gi;
oldDivContent = oldDivContent.replace(re,'<td id="idreplaceme"></td>');
```

or assuming the lawyers don't want you posting any part of `oldDivContent`, here's a JavaScript function that should work in lieu of a regex:

```
function removeContentOfIdentifiedTDs(content, id) {
    var d = document.createElement('div'),
        tr = {},
        td = {},
        i = 0;
    d.innerHTML = content; //add content to div
    td = d.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i += 1) {
        if (td[i].id === id) { //if id matches
            td[i].innerHTML = ''; //remove content
        }
    }
    return d.innerHTML; //return original html minus removed content
}
removeContentOfIdentifiedTDs(oldDivContent, 'idreplaceme');
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason the original wouldn't work on IE, or is this just a guess?

Comment: Just a guess (because it's IE) that the `.+?` is consuming more than it should.

Comment: @ pete: Apparently not, given reasonable assumptions for what the original content might be: http://jsbin.com/ajeqer, http://jsbin.com/ajeqer/2, http://jsbin.com/ajeqer/3, http://jsbin.com/ajeqer/4

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Given that your jsbin tests show it working in IE8, I'm guessing that the original content of `oldDivContent` cannot be assumed reasonably. :)

Comment: @ pete: They do. Until/unless the OP bothers to tell us what that content is, this is a non-question that should be closed and tossed.

Comment: This did not work for me in either IE8 or FF.  I've never seen it done this way but I'm not an expert on regex.  Is this method better for some reason?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Content is a large string.  I will try to remove the proprietary stuff so I can post a watered down example

Comment: @raido: Not better, per se, just different. The pattern `[^<]+` is a user-defined character class to match any character that is not a `<`. It will find the closing delimiter for the tag without requiring a non-greedy quantifier.

Comment: @pete: Your new regex will break on all browsers if `oldDivContent` is, say, `<td id="replaceme"><strong>Hi there</strong></td>`. raido didn't say that the text didn't and couldn't contain `<`.

Comment: @raido: Wrote a function that should do the job for you. Updated answer.

Comment: @pete:  Thanks so much. I made a small webpage using a modded version of your function and it worked perfectly on every browser.  I'm going to propose this next time I run into my boss.